# Does Firefox 3.6 support HTML 5?

Tags: firefox, html5, firefox-3.6

Does Firefox 3.6 support HTML 5?   If not, when is that support suppose to be added?

Comment: No browser will “support HTML5” in its entirity for a long time... not least because the spec isn't finished yet. However there are certainly parts of HTML5 you can use today (some of which have been spun off into their own spec).

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Firefox? The latest version is 51.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this Mozilla Developer's Wiki page: [HTML5 support in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML5_support_in_Mozilla).

Answer (score 1):

Well, HTML5 isn't finalised yet, but Firefox supports many of the new elements such as <video>

Comment: I believe Firefox only supports Ogg Theora video, however, so the upcoming YouTube <video> experiment won't work in Firefox, for example, because they will use H.264.

Comment: I gather that the video tag is supposed to gracefully fall back to whatever codecs one has on their machine at the time, so it should work, should youtube choose to let firefox in on the party.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5's spec isn't finalized and won't be until W3C's recommended status expected to come sometime in 2014. That said, yes, Firefox 3.6 does partially support the HTML5 spec, but only about 180 of the approximately 450 aspects added in HTML5.

I would expect to not see any browser fully supporting HTML5 until late 2013 or early 2014. Firefox 3.6 will never fully support HTML5 and it is recommended you upgrade if you wish to explore the possibilities made available in HTML5.

Source:

1. [The HTML5 Test - Desktop Browsers](http://html5test.com/results.html)